# Can't require 'config.php'?

Tags: php

Is `config.php` a reserved name or why is the following not working for me?

I have the following files:

`/test.php`:

```
echo "test<br/>";
require("php/session.php");
```

`/php/session.php`:

```
echo "session<br/>";
require("connect.php");
```

`/php/connect.php`:

```
echo "connect<br/>";
require("config.php");
```

`/php/config.php`:

```
echo "config<br/>";
```

If I open `/test.php`, it only prints `test`, `session` and `connect`. But if I rename `config.php` into something else and change the require in `connect.php`, it works.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you can include the file just by renaming it. What is the actual error message provided by PHP?

Comment: Are you sure that your filename was called that? As far as I know, there's no filename restrictions on the include/require functions.

Comment: is config.php in the php directory? perhaps change the require to `require("php/config.php");` or try `require('./config.php');`

Comment: Possibly session.php, and connect.php also exist in another directory, which is regarded by your script as the current directory. config.php isn't in that directory, so it fails. Can you output `getcwd()` and `__DIR__` and see if those values ring a bell?

Comment: @Mike: There's no error at all, it's just not included. If I have some variables defined in config.php, they are not visible anywhere else.

Comment: Turn on [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) then. If `require()` fails, it emits an [E_COMPILE_ERROR](http://php.net/require). So either it *is* actually requiring the file and you have a problem with [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) (however renaming the file wouldn't change that) or it's failing and you're not seeing the error. Also @GolezTrol gave you a possible situation that seems very probable to me. Were you able to figure anything out there?